# Distribution of joint Gaussian conditional on their sum

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X = (X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ be jointly Gaussian with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Let $S$ be their sum.

I know that the distribution of each $X_i \mid S = s$ is also Gaussian.

When $n=2$, I know that
$$
E\left( X_1\mid S = s \right) = s \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}
$$
and
$$
V\left(X_1\mid S = s \right) = \frac{\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}
$$
(see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17464) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/9071)). I could probably work out analogous expressions for an arbitrary $n$ if I sat down with a pencil and paper and worked at it for a bit.

What I want to know is, **what is the distribution of $X$ given $S = s$?**

I know that this can't be Gaussian, since the sum is bounded. It's clearly not Dirichlet or anything Dirichlet-esque, since the marginal distributions are Gaussian. But beyond that I don't have a clue.

Comment: I think it should be an $(n-1)$-dimensional Gaussian distribution which is supported one the hyperplane $\{\vec x :x_1+\dots+x_n=s\}$. The sum $X_1+\dots+X_n$ is bounded, but the sum $X_1+\dots+X_{n-1}$ is not.

Comment: @MikeEarnest that looks to me like a different distribution, conditional on both $S = s$ and $X_i = x$ for some $i$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let A be a deterministic matrix of size $n\times n$ and let $v$ be a vector of size $n$. The random vector $(AX, S)$ is jointly normal. The idea is to construct both

1. a matrix $A$ such that $AX$ is independent from $S$, and
2. a vector $v$ such that $X = AX + Sv$.

Why? Then by independence we have a crystal-clear description of the distribution of $X$ given $S=s$: The distribution of $X$ given $S=s$ is normal $$N(sv + A\mu, A\Sigma A^T)$$.

Now let's find such $A$ and $v$.

- Since $(AX,S)$ are jointly normal, $AX$ is independent from $S$ if and only if their covariance matrix is zero, that is,
  $E[A(X-\mu)(S - E[S])]=0$. If $u=(1,...,1)\in R^n$, this is equivalent to $E[A(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^T u] = A\Sigma u= 0$.
- For $v$, the relationship $X=AX +vS$ is satisfied provided that $I_n = A + vu^T$, where again $u$ is the vector $(1,...,1)$. Since $A\Sigma u =0$, multypling this by $\Sigma u$ implies that $$v = \frac{1}{u^T\Sigma u} \Sigma u.$$
  Now set $$A = I_n - v u^T.$$
  One readily verifies than such choice of $A$ indeed satisfies $A\Sigma u = 0$, and we have constructed $A$ and $v$ that satisfy the requirements.

---

#### More Generally: the distribution of $X$ given $UX=b$ for some matrix $U$

If $U$ is a $k\times n$ matrix of rank $k$ and we would like to find the distribution of $X$ conditionally on $UX$, the same technique can be extended.

(In the above example, $U$ is an $1\times n$ matrix equal to $u^T$.)

We proceed similarly: we look for deterministic matrix $A$ and a $n\times k$ matrix $C$ such that

1. $AX$ and $UX$ are independent, and
2. $I_n = A + CU$ so that $X = AX + CUX$ always holds.

Why? If we can find such matrices $A$ and $C$, then the distribution of $X$ given $UX=b$ is normal $$N(A\mu + Cb, A^T\Sigma A).$$

Since $AX$ and $UX$ are jointly Normal, the first condition holds if and only if $E[A(X-\mu)(U(X-\mu))^T] = A\Sigma U^T = 0$.
Multiyplying the second condition by $\Sigma U^T$, it must be that $\Sigma U^T  = C U \Sigma U^T$, hence
$$C = \Sigma U^T (U\Sigma U^T)^{-1} .$$

Finally, define
$$A = I_n - CU,$$
and check that this choice of $A$ and $C$ indeed satisfy $A\Sigma U^T = 0$ and the above requirements.

(By the way, the matrix $U\Sigma U^T$ is indeed invertible whenever $U$ is of full rank $k<n$ and $\Sigma$ is invertible. The matrix $\Sigma$ is invertible if and only if $X$ a continuous distribution in $R^n$ in the sens that it has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure in $R^n$.)

Comment: The result for $(\boldsymbol X | S = s)$ is correct if $\Gamma$ is the matrix of second *central* moments, that is, $\Gamma = \Sigma$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I started writing the answer for centered X and mixed things up to handle non-zero $\mu$. It's fixed now.

Comment: It seems like A should be $n \times n$ (not $(n-1) \times n$) in the first part.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @IanFiske

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of $(\boldsymbol X | S = s)$ is still jointly normal but degenerate. Let $\boldsymbol T = (1, 1, \dots, 1)^t$ and let $\boldsymbol X$ and $\boldsymbol \mu$ also be column vectors. Then $(X_1, \dots, X_n, \boldsymbol T^t \boldsymbol X)$ is jointly normal as an affine transform of a jointly normal distribution, and we can use the general formula for a conditional distribution of components of a jointly normal distribution:
$$(\boldsymbol X | \boldsymbol T^t \boldsymbol X = s) \sim
\mathcal N \!\left(
 \boldsymbol \mu + \frac
   {s - \boldsymbol \mu^t \boldsymbol T}
   {\boldsymbol T^t \Sigma \boldsymbol T}
  \Sigma \boldsymbol T,
 \Sigma - \frac 1 {\boldsymbol T^t \Sigma \boldsymbol T}
  \Sigma \boldsymbol T (\Sigma \boldsymbol T)^t
\right).$$
$\boldsymbol T$ is an eigenvector of the covariance matrix with the eigenvalue $0$.

Comment: Maxim, just for notation, $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of the original random vector, ${\bf X}$; and $t$ is the transposing, right?

Comment: Correct, $\boldsymbol X \sim \mathcal N(\boldsymbol \mu, \Sigma)$, and $\boldsymbol T^t$ is a row vector.