# Conditioning on an event, Gaussian inner product is fixed.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, gaussian-integral

Say I have an $n-$dimensional  random vector ${\bf X}$ with iid standard normal entries. Fix a vector $A\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Question:** Does the distribution of ${\bf X}$, conditional on $\langle A,{\bf X}\rangle$ is known? It feels like should be something known. As a further alternative, does, say, $\mathbb{E}[\langle B,{\bf X}\rangle|\langle A,{\bf X}\rangle=t]$ is known? ($B\neq A$)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2943590) and replace $\boldsymbol T$ with $\boldsymbol A$.

Comment: Thank you. I've posted a quick question therein, would appreciate if you answer that.