# Given the L2 norm of a Gaussian matrix, what distribution does the Gaussian matrix follow?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, matrix-norms, chi-squared

Given a random gaussian matrix **X** with zero mean matrix and covariance matrix **Σ**, and two deterministic matrices **A** and **B**. If I know the value of $||{\bf{AX}}||_F^2$, how could I get the pdf of $||{\bf{BX}}||_F^2$ ($||{\bf{P}}||_F^2$ is the L2 norm of matrix **P**)?

In my opinion, since **X** is a random gaussian matrix, $||{\bf{AX}}||_F^2$ follows chi-square distribution and its pdf can be calculated. However, if I obtain the value of the random variable $||{\bf{AX}}||_F^2$ without knowing specific **X**, the pdf of **X** and the pdf of $||{\bf{BX}}||_F^2$ are not obvious.

What I want to know is, **what are the distributions of **X** and $||{\bf{BX}}||_F^2$ given $||{\bf{AX}}||_F^2=a$**? Or, is there any method to get the pdf of $||{\bf{BX}}||_F^2$ given $||{\bf{AX}}||_F^2=a$ without calculating the pdf of **X**.

I have learned the pdf of **X** given S=s, where S is the sum of all elements of **X** [Distribution of joint Gaussian conditional on their sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784531/distribution-of-joint-gaussian-conditional-on-their-sum?rq=1). But it seems quite different from this question.