# Expected value of $X$ given $a^TX$ if X has a multivariate normal distribution.

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Let $X$ be a normally distributed random vector with mean vector $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. Also, let Y be a random vector such that $Y = a^TX$ where $a$ is a constant vector. How would I go about computing E(X|Y = y).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2784531/distribution-of-joint-gaussian-conditional-on-their-sum